# JQUERY. list apprenticer

Tags: php, c++

But i can't seem to get it to work..

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#theUL").on('click', 'li', function () {
    if ($(this).css('textDecoration') == 'lineunder') {
      $(this).css('textDecoration', 'none');
    } else {
      $(this).css('textDecoration', 'lineunder');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: were is your html

Comment: Why not just use a class to apply your style?  Then you could just do this:

 if($(this).is('.withStrike')) {$(this).removeClass('withStrike');} else {$(this).addClass('withStrike')}

Comment: even better, use toggleClass('className') and save a few lines

Comment: try to console.log($(this)) and check what will be output

Answer (score 4):

Use [**toggleClass**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to add or remove class from the element.This will reduce the number of lines in your code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#theUL").on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('colorText')
  });
});
```

```css
.colorText {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="theUL">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because when you get the CSS property with jQuery of the text-decoration, it returns also the color. If you want to use this property, you should add the check for the color too in the if. This should do what you are looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#theUL").on('click', 'li', function () {
    if ($(this).css('text-decoration') == 'line-through solid rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
      $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
    } else {
      $(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="theUL">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ul>
```

By the way you can do it easier and cleaner using CSS classes instead of changing styles in this way

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#theUL li").on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).css('text-decoration') == 'line-through') {
      $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
    } else {
      $(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
    }
  });
});
```

The this in this context it's the UL, if you use the code above, you make sure that it's the li the this in the context

Comment: This code won't work because the `text-decoration` property never is exactly `line-through`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Change your selector to access the `li` elements directly.
2. Your test for `line-through` will never be met because the property contains more than just that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#theUL > li").on('click', function () {
    // The `text-decoration` CSS property contains more than just 'line-through'
    console.log($(this).css('text-decoration'));
  
    if ($(this).css('text-decoration') == 'line-through solid rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
      $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
    } else {
      $(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="theUL">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to change your if-statement condition to:

```
if ($(this).css('text-decoration') == 'line-through solid rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
    ...
}
```

Setting the CSS using `$(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through')` will do some things in the background as default CSS items are still set, such as the solid line and color.